# Validação de informações de login não funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, validação

As dúvidas estão ao longo do programa

```
import string


alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

n = range(0, 10)
name = input('Digite seu nome de usuário:')


if name in n:
    while True:
        print('Apenas letras são permitidas na nomeação do usuário.')
        name = input('Digite seu nome de usuário:')
        #o loop só encerra quando apenas uma letra é digitada, mais que isso já não dá certo. 
        if name not in n:
            break
if name not in alphabet:
    while True:
        print('Apenas letras são permitidas na nomeação do usuário.')
        name = input('Digite seu nome de usuário:')
        if name in alphabet:
            break


password = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
l = range(8, 17)
o = [',', ',', '@', '#', '$', '%', '¨', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', ':', '}', '{', 'º', '|']#Tentei colocar manualmente todos os caracteres que não são permitidos em senhas, porque procurei e não achei uma forma de adicioná-los como fiz na variável do alfabeto.

if password == name:
    while True:
        print('!Informações!\n\nSua senha não pode ser igual ao seu nome de usuário.\n')
        password = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
        if password != name:
            break


elif len(password) not in l:
    while True:
        print('\n\nSua senha deve ter no mínimo 8 e no máximo 16 caracteres.\n')
        password = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
        if len(password) in l:
            break
elif password not in alphabet:
    while True:
        print('\n\nSua senha deve conter letras e números.\n')
        password = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
        if password in alphabet:
            break
elif password not in n:
    while True:
        print('\n\nSua senha deve conter letras e números.\n')
        password = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
        if password in n:
            break
#com alguns números e letras dão certo e o loop se encerra, mas com outros números e letras o loop permanece.


elif password in o:
    while True:
        print('\n\nApenas letras e números são permitidos.\n')
        password = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
        if password not in o:
            break


password_2 = input('Digite novamente sua senha:')


else:
    if password_2 != password:
        while True:
            print('Suas senhas não coincidem, tente novamente.')
            if password_2 == password:
                break

print('Usuário registrado com sucesso.')
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Algumas observações que vão te colocar no rumo certo:

- Verifique se a entrada está dentro dos parâmetros, não verifique se ela está fora. Pode parecer bobo, mas só aceite o que pode ser aceito e mantenha a quantidade de coisas aceitas em uma faixa que você tem controle.
- Utilize operadores e funções padrões da linguagem que foram disponibilizadas para a tarefa de forma mais simples possível. Então use maior e menor para comparar uma faixa e use [`isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum), por exemplo, para determinar se está na faixa que deseja.
- Não pode adianta tentar verificar se uma *string* está contida dentro de um uma lista de caracteres, só será verdadeiro se a *string* tiver só um caracteres.
- Peça o dado apenas uma vez, se a pessoa tem que entrar de novo tem que ser no mesmo local do código, ou seja, só deve ter 3 `input()` (e 3 variáveis) neste código. Um dos motivos do erro é a lógica complexa demais. Este código ser muito mais simples e curto, aí dá para achar o erro mais fácil e até eliminá-lo sozinho.

Assim:

```
while True:
    name = input('Digite seu nome de usuário:')
    if not name.isalpha():
        print('Apenas letras são permitidas na nomeação do usuário.')
    else:
        break
while True:
    password = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
    if password == name:
        print('\n\nSua senha não pode ser igual ao seu nome de usuário.\n')
    elif len(password) < 8 or len(password) > 16:
        print('\n\nSua senha deve ter no mínimo 8 e no máximo 16 caracteres.\n')
    elif not (any(char.isdigit() for char in password) and any(char.isalpha() for char in password)):
        print('\n\nSua senha deve conter letras e números.\n')
    else:
        break
while True:
    password2 = input('Digite sua nova senha:')
    if password2 != password:
        print('Suas senhas não coincidem, tente novamente.')
    else:
        break
print('Usuário registrado com sucesso.')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GelUZz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ahfetnrg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/PasswordEntry.py).

Comment: Se tem algum erro, favor informar para eu poder corrigir.